# Hadoop Mapreduce: TextInputFormat and processing lines?

Tags: text, hadoop, mapreduce, line, textinput

I'm not really sure if I understand the way TextInputFormat works. In the documentation it says:

> An InputFormat for plain text files. Files are broken into lines.

So I assumed that when I simply transform the value I get as an Input to my map function to String I would have a String representation of a line in my file.

```
    public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

    String line = value.toString(); \\ one line of my input file?
    ...

    }
```

However upon further processing the line it turns out that it actually isn't a line from my file. My file city.dat looks like this:

```
Andorra la Vella|ad|Andorra la Vella|20430|42.51|1.51
Canillo|ad|Canillo|3292|42.57|1.6
...
```

Can anyone tell me how I can have the process the lines of this file in my map function?

Comment: In case of TextInputFormat, the value to the map is a line from the input. If it is not then some thing might have been messed in the program.

Comment: So are you sure that the value only contains a single line of my input file?

Comment: What is the result from value.toString()?  And are there any other files in the same directory as your input file?  If you give a directory name then all files in the directory are read as input.

Comment: there is only one file in my input directoy. city.dat which contains all entries in the above style

Comment: What specifically is the line that you are getting that isn't in the input file, and what specifically are you expecting?

Answer (score 1):

The TextInputFormat works as An InputFormat for plain text files. Files are broken into lines. Either linefeed or carriage-return are used to signal end of line. Keys are the position in the file, and values are the line of text..
If the end of line is not a line feed or carriage return in ur case u have to write ur own InputFormat.

Check out this blog point no. 3 its sure to broken down the lines at the end of line.
http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2011/01/lessons-learned-from-clouderas-hadoop-developer-training-course/

I suggest to check out ur file by opening  the file into TextEditor like UltraEdit and check the new line character.

See if it helps.